# Null content digitally signed message

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature

IA technical specification I'm following requires me to send:

> The Digital Signature must be in the form of a null content Digitally
>   Signed message (i.e. a PKCS#7 object containing the signature but not
>   the data that was signed).

To my understanding, this means a detached PKCS#7 signature, is that correct?

I couldn't find any definition of what a "Null Content Digitally Signed message" is.
So a PKCS#7 detached seems the closest match..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. At the ASN.1 level, it means that the `OCTET STRING` field (`EncapsulatedContentInfo.eContent`) is omitted (it is marked `OPTIONAL` precisely to allow for detached signatures -- the expression "null content" in that context is new to me, the usual term being "detached signature" as you correctly infer).

Answer (score 7):

> (i.e. a PKCS#7 object containing the signature but not the data that was signed)

That describes exactly what a detached signature is, a signature separated from the data which was signed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick confirmation mikeazo, it's all I needed but I'm accepting Thomas answer for the additional useful info.